# HTML Helpers DropDownList On change Jquery Event filter another DropDownList? MVC Example attached

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-helper

i have select option like,

```
   <td>
                    <select id="ddlregion" name="RegionId">
                        <option value="0">Select Region</option>
                        @foreach (Region re in region)
                        {
                            <option value="@re.RegionID">@re.RegionName</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select disabled id="ddlcity" name="CityId">
                        <option value="0">Select City</option>
                        @foreach (City re in city)
                        {
                            <option data-region="@re.RegionID" value="@re.CityID">@re.CityName</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </td>
```

Onchange i am calling method,

```
$("body").on("change", "#ddlregion", function () {
    var selectedRegion = $(this).val();
    $('#ddlcity').prop('disabled', false);
    $("#ddlcity").find("option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).data("region") == selectedRegion) {
            $(this).show();

        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

It is working fine.

Now i am trying to use same approach in HTML helpers DropDownList,

```
   <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegionId, "RegionId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("RegionId", null, new { @class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegionId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityId, "CityId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CityId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @data_region="RegionId" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>




 $("body").on("change", "#RegionId", function () {
        var selectedRegion = $(this).val();
        alert("test");
        $('#CityId').prop('disabled', false);
        $("#CityId").find("option").each(function () {
            if ($(this).data("region") == selectedRegion) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });

using above script it not not calling on change.
```

than i make change in region dropdown and change script like this,

```
@Html.DropDownList("RegionId", null, new { @class = "form-control",onchange="callChangefunc(this.value)"})

   function callChangefunc(val) {
        var selectedRegion = $(this).val();
        alert("test");
        $('#CityId').prop('disabled', false);
        $("#CityId").find("option").each(function () {
            if ($(this).data("region") == selectedRegion) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here i am getting this error,

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Hopes for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Either `this`  might actually be a window reference; or, on DOM load, the context of `this` will not be the drop down ref yet.

So manually, just trigger a change() event on the #CityId element on load of the DOM:

```
$("#CityId").change(loadRegion).change(); // or .trigger('change');
```

Optionally just use $.proxy to change the context the function runs under:

```
$("#CityId").change(loadRegion);
$.proxy(loadRegion, $('#RegionSelect'))();
```

Comment: can you tell how my function look like after changing